# On successmultiple function in Dropzone.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, dropzone.js, dropzone

I'm trying to alert the user when their files have been successfully uploaded but am stuck on getting it to work after the init function.

Here is my script:

```
<script>
    Dropzone.options.myDropzone = {
        paramName: 'file',
        maxFilesize: 10, // MB
        maxFiles: 20,
        acceptedFiles: ".jpeg,.jpg,.png,.gif,.pdf,.doc,.docx,.xlsx,.xls",
    };

     this.on("successmultiple", function (file) {
          alert("All files have uploaded ");
      });
</script>
```

The upload does work so I am assuming it is how I am calling the successmultiple portion.

Comment: One thing I see from the [docs](http://www.dropzonejs.com/#event-successmultiple) is that, this function is allowed only when `uploadMultiple` is set to `true`. Try setting that and see it if works.

Comment: I ended up realizing that I needed to use: queuecomplete rather, which was the more appropriate option instead. Thank you for the help though!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up realizing that I needed to use: queuecomplete rather, which was the more appropriate option instead. (See: http://www.dropzonejs.com/#events)